# Can’t send token in metamask

Tags: contract-development, metamask

Hi all always when i send token it said (BEP-20 Token Transfer Error (Unable to locate corresponding Transfer Event Logs), Check with Sender. what we can do in this case?

Comment: Can you share the transaction id? It seems the contract is failing without more details it could be anything: gas limit too low, using the wrong amount, a contract bug, a scam contract, etc.